# not able to print on PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing, printer, print-drivers

A PC running Windows 7 used to send messages to the printer. It is connected using USB. Other PCs continue to work well with the printer. The printer is HP deskjet F380. Could this behavior be caused by a virus? How could I fix it?

Comment: What is the model of the printer? Have you installed the latest printer drivers from the manufacturer's website?

Comment: That isn't typical virus behavior, but there isn't really enough information here for people to know what the problem is.  How did you test it with other computers (physically connect it with the same cable vs. access it over a network)?  Have you tried connecting it to a different USB port (especially on another side of the PC)?  Do other USB devices work on the same ports? Have you rebooted the PC?  Have you tried clearing the spooler?  Checked the device manager for problem flags?  Tried reinstalling the printer driver?  Checked the hard drive for corruption?

Comment: I tried it with other comuters, I rebooted the PC.

Comment: Determining how to fix it requires figuring out what the problem is.  That's a methodical troubleshooting process to rule out potential causes.  This site wasn't really designed for that; it focuses on problems for which there is an answer that can be determined from the information provided.  We can ask clarifying questions in comments, but there isn't a practical method to explain how to conduct each possible diagnostic in order to get to the question of how to fix a specific, defined problem.  The site also discourages the shotgun approach of collecting possible answers based on guesses.

Comment: (cont'd) Do you know anyone with some computer experience who can help to at least narrow down the possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting and cleaning the print spooler?

Step 1
Click the "Start" button on your Windows desktop. Type "services.msc" in the search bar and click "Services" from the results.

Step 2
Scroll down and click on "Print Spooler" in the list of services. Click "Stop."

Step 3
Click the "Start" button and then click "Computer" from the Windows Start menu. (Click "File Explorer" for Windows 10) Double-click "Local Disk (C:)."

Step 4
Double-click "Windows" and "System32." Double-click "Spool" and "Printers."

Step 5
Right-click each file in the Printers folder. Click "Delete" and "Yes."

Step 6
Go back to the Service window and start the "Print Spooler" by right clicking it, then click on "Start."

Source: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/clean-print-spooler-48277.html

Comment: Thank for pitching in to help others. For the sake of improvement, I want to point out that asking questions in the answer area is frowned upon. If this is the answer you believe will solve the OP's issue, then state so. Suggestions of things to try should be made in the comments.

Comment: I do apologize about that.  I'm new here.  I'm not trying to be rude or anything and I honestly didn't know about writing "questions" in the answers.  What if I had written it as "Try restarting and cleaning the print spooler."  Or "Restarting and cleaning the print spooler."   Oh also, I couldn't "comment" on other people's posts until I had 50 reps.  I think I can now...

Comment: No worries or need to apologize. I am just making you aware. The idea is we want to answer when we know what the proper answer is. Granted, we don't always get the details needed from the original poster (OP), so sometimes we do guess. The point is, YES, make it a statement, not a question. Something like "Restarting the print spooler often resolves these issues. Here is how to do it" would sound much better. **BTW, Good job adding a source.** Taking a [tour] can help immensely to improving asking and answering.

Comment: One problem you're running into is trying to answer a question that is too broad.  Answers are intended to be definitive solutions that other people can find if they have the same problem.  This kind of question is very hard to answer within the site's limitations.  You end up with a lot of guesses, all of which could be wrong.  The best solution is to get the OP in a chat room and go through diagnostics to figure out what the problem actually is.  Then the question can be refined and clarified, and the right answer posted.